# How can I transfer just modified files?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, move

I want to transfer files From **A** folder to **B** folder.But I want to just transfer last modifed date changed files, is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at Windows ROBOCOPY command. It can easily do what you are asking.

Comment: @dbenham should I install something for robocopy comand?

Comment: `robocopy` is a default command in Vista and higher, and is available as a download from Microsoft for XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided details of the operating system you're using, but assuming it's Linux or Mac you could use rsync.

Have a look at this thread which gives a couple of examples: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=100176

If you're on Windows, SyncBack or DeltaCopy software programs might be a good solution.

Comment: http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

I haven't used it myself as I use Mac and Linux, but a quick search on Google threw that link up.

Comment: It works every one minute at least  I want to copy when a new file exists so I want to copy when a new file appears in my folder which copy from it.